# Import existing project into android studio but external library (com.google.android.gms) not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to give android studio a try that Google announce at IO. I've got it installed and working and imported my existing project from subversion and created an android studio project. Everything seems to be OK except for an issue with one of the libraries, I think it relates to the Drive library `com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker`. In the log it says that `com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker does not exist`.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Were you using Eclipse?  There is a special technique you can use to migrate Eclipse projects to Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: I followed this closely and am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

File->Project Structure->Modules

add a new Module than choose your main module and add the new Module to the dependencies

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIc15.png

[image]